# Get links that friends have "liked" on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I was wondering how to build a FQL query where i could receive links/urls of my app that an user's friends have liked. I got the link table which looks good but there i need an object id, which i dunno how to retrieve for my urls.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the object id from the `object_url` table.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/object_url/